# using the Newton binomial formula to prove $\sharp 2^x=2^{\sharp x}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using the Newton binomial formula to prove.
$\sharp 2^x=2^{\sharp x}$, were $x$ - set is finished.
For $2^x$ it's easy. Using mathematical induction. 
But how to do it ?

Comment: What does $\#$ mean in this context?

Comment: sharp is a power set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that $2^x$ means the power set $\mathcal P(x)$, and $\sharp$ denotes the cardinality.

1. Using the Newton binomial formula.
   $$
   2^x=\bigcup_{k=0}^{\sharp x}\{A\subset x\mid\sharp A=k\}
   $$

So $\sharp2^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\sharp x}\sharp\{A\in x\mid\sharp A=k\}$. For all $0\le k\le\sharp x$, an subset $A\subset x$ such that $\sharp A=k$ is characterised by the choice of $k$ elements of $x$ among $\sharp x$ possibilities, that is $\binom\sharp k$ possibilities. Therefore, by the Newton binomial formula,
$$
\sharp2^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\sharp x}\sharp\{A\in x\mid\sharp A=k\}=\sum_{k=0}^{\sharp x}\binom \sharp k=\sum_{k=0}^{\sharp x}\binom \sharp k1^k1^{\sharp x-k}=(1+1)^{\sharp x}=2^{\sharp x}
$$

2. Using induction.

If $\sharp x=0$ then $x=\emptyset$ and $2^x=\mathcal P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$, so $\sharp 2^x=1=2^0=2^{\sharp x}$ so the assertion is true for $\sharp x=0$.

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Suppose that the assertion is true for any set $x$ such that $\sharp x=n$.
Let $x$ be a set such that $\sharp x=n+1$. Let $a\in x$, so that $x=(x\backslash\{a\})\cup\{a\}$. Then
$$
2^x=\{A\mid A\in2^{x\backslash\{a\}}\}\cup\{A\cup\{a\}\mid A\in 2^{x\backslash\{a\}}\},
$$
hence $\sharp2^x=2\times\sharp2^{x\backslash\{a\}}=2\times2^{\sharp(x\backslash\{a\})}=2^{1+\sharp(x\backslash\{a\})}=2^{\sharp x}$, where we used the induction assumption for $x\backslash\{a\}$.

By induction, we deduce that for any finite set $x$, we have $\sharp 2^x=2^{\sharp x}$.

3. Another method.

Let $f:2^x\to\{0,1\}^x$ be defined for all $y\subset x$ by
$$
f(y)=(1_y(A))_{A\in x},
$$
where $1_y(A)=1$ if $A\in y$ and $1_y(A)=0$ otherwise. It is easy to see that $f$ is one-to-one and onto, so $\sharp 2^x=\sharp\{0,1\}^x=2^{\sharp x}$.